# add/remove css class to div via shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinyjs

I have a select menu in shiny like below.

```
selectInput(
        "mySelectMenu",
        "",
        c(1,2),
        selected = NULL,
        multiple = FALSE
      )
```

Actions are observed on this element like below

```
observeEvent(input$mySelectMenu,{
    currentIndividual<-as.numeric(input$mySelectMenu)
    toggleFunction(currentIndividual)
},ignoreInit=TRUE)
```

In the inspector, I can see this the div that holds this dropdown content. It's html looks like this

```
<div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
   <div data-value="1" data-selectable="" class="option selected">318_2007</div>
   <div data-value="2" data-selectable="" class="option">320_2007</div>
   <div data-value="3" data-selectable="" class="option">321_2007</div>
   <div data-value="4" data-selectable="" class="option">344_2009</div>
   <div data-value="5" data-selectable="" class="option">346_2009</div>
   <div data-value="6" data-selectable="" class="option">355_2009</div>
</div>
```

And it visually looks like this

[image]

Finally, I'd like to change the look on some of these menu items in certain instances. A specific scenario... I want the div with 'data-value="2"' to have **BOLD RED** text. How could I specifically add/remove the CSS class below (.menuItemInactive) from the div with data-value='2'? I am already using shiny.js and would be happy to use it or any other package for this task.

```
.menuItemInactive{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Create a media query where `@media (data-value: 2) {...}`?

Comment: @RyanMorton - Sounds promising. Can you provide a more detailed answer?

Comment: @media (data-value: 2) {.option{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}}

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure it'll work. Selector is probably a better solution: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with the **shinyjs** package and the runjs method.
In the second observeEvent function, you check which value from the selectInput is chosen and then accordingly, you change the css properties of that div.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  tabItem(tabName = "comp",
          fluidRow(
            selectInput("mySelectMenu", "",c(1,2,3),selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE
            )))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  observeEvent(input$mySelectMenu,{
    currentIndividual<-as.numeric(input$mySelectMenu)
    # toggleFunction(currentIndividual)
  },ignoreInit=TRUE)

  observeEvent(input$mySelectMenu, {
    if (input$mySelectMenu == 1) {
      runjs(paste0('$(".selectize-input").css({"color": "red", "font-weight": "bold"})'))
    }
    if (input$mySelectMenu == 2) {
      runjs(paste0('$(".selectize-input").css({"color": "blue", "font-weight": "bold"})'))
    }
    if (input$mySelectMenu == 3) {
      runjs(paste0('$(".selectize-input").css({"color": "green", "font-weight": "bold"})'))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It just applies the css if an item is selected, if the dropdown box is opened, all items are still black. Do you want it to allways have the desired colors, or is this solution fine for you?

Comment: This is really close to what I have tried. I noticed the same thing you mention about the dropdown. Even if I change the style/class of the items, once the dropdown opens, those styles and classes are cleared. Any idea how to get around that issue?

Answer (score 2):

Then I think a combination of @kluu and my previous answer would do the trick.
But like this, the order of the items determines the color in the dropdown-modus, not their data-value.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  inlineCSS(".selectize-dropdown-content > .option:nth-child(1) {
            font-weight:bold;
            color:red;
            }
            .selectize-dropdown-content > .option:nth-child(2) {
            font-weight:bold;
            color:blue;
            }
            .selectize-dropdown-content > .option:nth-child(3) {
            font-weight:bold;
            color:green;
            }

            "
  ),
  tabItem(tabName = "comp",
          fluidRow(
            selectInput("mySelectMenu", "",c(1,2,3),selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE
            )))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  observeEvent(input$mySelectMenu,{
    currentIndividual<-as.numeric(input$mySelectMenu)
    # toggleFunction(currentIndividual)
  },ignoreInit=TRUE)

  observeEvent(input$mySelectMenu, {
    if (input$mySelectMenu == 1) {
      runjs(paste0('$(".selectize-input").css({"color": "red", "font-weight": "bold"})'))
    }
    if (input$mySelectMenu == 2) {
      runjs(paste0('$(".selectize-input").css({"color": "blue", "font-weight": "bold"})'))
    }
    if (input$mySelectMenu == 3) {
      runjs(paste0('$(".selectize-input").css({"color": "green", "font-weight": "bold"})'))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the color does not depend on the value it holds, but rather on the order of appearance in the list, you could use `nth-child`:

```
.selectize-dropdown-content > .option:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:red;
}
```